# When I apply a texture to my mesh some parts aren't well rendered

Tags: modeling

When I apply a texture to my mesh some parts aren't well rendered. I dont know why :

[image]

[image]

Thanks !

Comment: Please [edit] your question and images of your shader nodes. Is your object unwrapped?

Comment: I uploaded the image. It may be related to a "texture loop cut" I tried it but its not working.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you unwrapped your cube initially, and then procceeded to model some more but never unwrapped the modified object. Now your UVmap is that of the original cube, and that does not match the current state of the object, so your texture looks a bit of a mess.

Example:

Default Cube:
[image]

Slightly Modified, not unwrapped again:
[image]

Simply reset your UVmap, <kbd>U</kbd> *>reset* <kbd>R</kbd> then unwrap again. <kbd>U</kbd> *follow active quads* (with the last selected quad face active) is usually my go to, but use whichever method that gives the result you require for your needs.

For instance, this is my modified cube with a new UVmap:
[image]